# netbeans form loading issues

Tags: user-interface, forms, netbeans, code-generation

```
Error in loading component: [jDialog]->mainPanel->titleBar
cannot create instance of <qualified classname>
The component cannot be loaded.

Error in loading layout: [JDialog]->mainPanel->[layout]
Failed to initialize layout of this container

Errors occured in loading the form data. It is not recommended to use this form now in editable mode - data that could not be loaded would be lost after saving the form. Please go through the reported errors, try to fix them if possible, and open the form again. If you choose to open the form as View Only you may see which beans are missing.
```

recently moved a class that was being used in several forms but all the paths in both form and java files were updated to point to the new location. Anyone know what could cause an error like this?

Things I have tried: clean + build, removeing and re-adding all library jar files, making sure the title bar and the old version in SVN were identical except for the package changes. Doing the same comparison with their respective form files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the View menu there is an IDE log option that allowed me to see what was happening behind the scenes to cause this error.

custom code for the text of one of the labels was throwing an exception.